# Why Spring data throwing java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data. on executing native mysql query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am executing the following `mysql` query using `spring-data-jpa`,

```
select 'FIRM NAME', 'USER_NAME', 'EMAIL', 'USER_PHONE', 'CLICK_COUNT', 'CLICK_DATE', 'PARTNER NAME'
 union all select * from (select cf.cf_firm_name, u.u_name, u.u_email, u.u_phone, co.c_clicks,
 co.c_click_date, p.p_name from click_offer co inner join user u on co.c_user_id = u.u_id inner join
 c_firm cf on u.u_cpa_firm = cf.cf_id inner join offer of on co.c_offer_id = of.o_id inner join
 partner p on of.o_partner_id = p.p_id) a into outfile '/var/lib/mysql-files/aafa.csv' fields
 terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n';
```

But on executing `hibernate` is throwing the exception after successfully creating the file,

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:6301)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.next(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:987)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692)
    ... 110 common frames omitted
```

But when I try to run the same query on `mysql-workbench`, it is executing without the error.

I am using the following code to execute the query from spring,

```
String query= DynamicQueryGenerator.queryToFetchOttomartClickCountDetails(ottoMartCsvGeneratorBean);

            Query executableQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
                        executableQuery.setParameter("from", fromDate);
            executableQuery.setParameter("to", toDate);
            if (!NullEmptyUtils.isNullorEmpty(ottoMartCsvGeneratorBean.getFirmIds())){
                executableQuery.setParameter("firmIds", ottoMartCsvGeneratorBean.getFirmIds());
            }
            executableQuery.getResultList();
```

where `query` contains the `mysql` query to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems to be meant to write something into a file, not to return a resultset.

[getResultList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList()) expects results to be returned from the query.

Try calling :

```
executableQuery.executeUpdate()
```